# By convention does Qt allow signals and slots to have different signatures?

Tags: c++, qt

I assumed from experience with Qt that all signals and slots required identical signatures. Recently I seen Qt code that connects totally different signatures, and the slot are called when the signal they were connected to is emitted. For example, a signal that emits a couple objects to a slot that takes no arguments.

I know about the different ways QObject::connect() can be called for connecting signals and slots, still I figured the rule was that their signatures are required to be the same.

Comment: At least, Qt allows signals to have more arguments than slots. Extra arguments are dropped. Convenient when connecting, say, `QCombobox::currentIndexChanged` (passing a an `int`) to a slot that only cares that the selection changed, but not what it changed to.

Comment: I've always kept my signals and slots with the same signatures. There's advantages to allowing different function signatures, but never thought it was an intended feature.

Comment: I have on a few occasions had less arguments for the slot than the signal if I did not care about them.

Comment: I prefer to keep the signatures the same for signals//slots and not provide a name for a parameter if it's not being used. Also this helps when reading the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [Qt Signals and Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots):

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving
> slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it
> receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)

Essentially, you can drop arguments from the end of your slot's signature (you can **not** drop them from the beginning or middle).

If you need to ignore arbitrary arguments, you can make your slot's signature identical to the signal and then use the [`Q_UNUSED` macro](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_UNUSED) for any arguments you want to ignore.  For example:

```
void MyClass::mySlot(int foo, double argIDontCareAbout, int bar)
{
    Q_UNUSED(argIDontCareAbout)
}
```

The point of the `Q_UNUSED` macro is to simply to suppress compiler warnings about unused arguments.