# How (and why!) do PySide6 signals call slots with mismatching signatures?

Tags: python, signature, signals-slots, pyside6

In this naive example, `QSpinBox.valueChanged`, which is a signal passing an `int`, is able to call the slot `fun()` which does not accept an int. For some reason, this works. Why?

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSpinBox

def fun():
    print("This works, but why? box.valueChanged passes an int!")

app = QApplication()
box = QSpinBox()
box.valueChanged.connect(fun)
box.setValue(10)
```

The problem becomes obvious when I add a decorator the slot, in which case I am getting the (expected?)

> TypeError: decorated_fun() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

I wonder how `PySide6` is able to call `fun` in the first place, and if I can call `inner` within the decorator in a similarly forgiving way. That latter part is answered in my answer below, but *why* does PySide6 do something like this in the first place, and can I disable such behavior?

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSpinBox

def fun():
    print("This works, but why?")

def my_decorator(inner):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return inner(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def decorated_fun():
    print("This fails")

app = QApplication()
box = QSpinBox()
box.valueChanged.connect(fun)
box.valueChanged.connect(decorated_fun)
box.setValue(10)
```

I also tried the `decorator` package, but I am getting essentially the same error:

```py
from decorator import decorator
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSpinBox

def fun():
    print("This works, but why?")

@decorator
def my_decorator(inner, *args, **kwargs):
    return inner(*args, **kwargs)

@my_decorator
def decorated_fun():
    print("This fails")

app = QApplication()
box = QSpinBox()
box.valueChanged.connect(fun)
box.valueChanged.connect(decorated_fun)
box.setValue(10)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71906000/

Comment: Related: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

You are not connecting to the function, but to the wrapper, which indeed accepts arguments; what happens is that, when the wrapper actually calls the real function, the exception is raised because that function is called with the wrong arguments.

### How signals and slots work

First of all, consider how signals and slots actually work in Qt while used with pure C++. As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots):

> The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)

Note the last phrase, which is extremely important: the argument types of the slots can be a subset of the signal signature (as long as they are in the proper order).

Let's consider the case of the [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) signal:

> **`void QSpinBox::valueChanged(int i)`**

This means two things:

- the signal could only be connected to a slot that accepts a single argument, and that argument type must be an integer;
- considering the note above, the signal can also be connected to a slot that has **no** argument at all;

Qt is able to determine the signature of that slot, and if it has a signature compatible with that of the signal (one integer argument, or no arguments at all) the connection is successful.

Note that the "subset" considers the order of arguments: a signal with signature `(int, str, int)` can be connected to a slot that accepts `(int, str)`, but not `(str, int)`.

### On the Python side

Let's go back to the Python implementation. Remember that PySide (and PyQt, on which PySide is conceptually based) is a *wrapper* around the C++ Qt library, and in order to make that binding work some quirks and workarounds are done in the abstraction layer between those two languages.
Also, Qt knows absolutely **nothing** about Python. To its "knowledge", it's just working normally as a standard Qt program written and compiled in C++.

When connecting to a pure Python function, Qt has no knowledge about the signature of the function (remember that type hints in Python are just *hints*: they are irrelevant at runtime, and do not normally cause exceptions if they are "wrong"). It just "accepts" the connection and no type checking is done; it's almost like connecting to a "slot" that has the "right" signature.

The following code will not cause any issue:

```py
def someFunction(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)
box.valueChanged.connect(someFunction)
```

Then, try to add the following line:

```py
box.setValue(2)
```

The above raises an exception, then:

```py
TypeError: someFunction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

Note that, at least in PyQt, the type checking will be done with a real slot created with the `pyqtSlot` decorator, and if the signatures don't match it will raise a `TypeError` exception about that.

Remember that the slot decorator has only two primary purposes:

- provide the possibility of signal overrides (the same signal name with different signatures);
- allow proper detection of the *context* in which the slot exists (normally useful only for objects existing in different threads);

Also remember that python decorators for Qt (both PySide and PyQt) only work and make sense when used on methods of a QObject instance. Using the `Slot` or `pyqtSlot` decorator on a normal function is completely pointless.

Considering all the above, that's why the connection (and subsequent call when the signal is emitted) is successful when connecting to `fun()`.

### The issue with the decorator wrapper

We now know that any function can be connected to a signal, no matter its argument count, and even if they don't match (a signal with different arguments or less arguments than the target function/slot).

Your decorator actually returns a function that can take *any* parameter. When that "wrapper" is called, everything is fine: using `*args, **kwargs` allows it to be successfully called with any argument, including no positional argument or unknown keyworded arguments.

Since the `wrapper` function accepts any positional argument, it's actually called with the value of the spinbox: `*args` actually is `(<new value>, )`.

Then, you call the `inner()` function (aka, `decorated_fun`) with those same arguments, and there you get the exception.

Let's see what actually happens, step by step:

1. the user changes the value of the spin box to `2`;
2. the `valueChanged` signal is emitted;
3. the wrapper is called with the new value as its only argument, which fundamentally is like calling `wrapper(2)`;
4. `wrapper` has a signature that accepts any positional argument, so the call above will not have any problem;
5. `wrapper` calls the `inner` function with the same arguments, which is like calling `decorated_fun(2)`;
6. `decorated_fun()` doesn't accept positional arguments, so the exception is raised;

### PySide/PyQt slot decorators

In your question you don't mention the Python slot decorators, but it's important to be aware about the distinction.

There is a fundamental difference between your decorator and a Python slot one, which is also the cause of the issue above: your decorator returns a *different* function that finally calls the given one, while the Python slot always returns the *same* function.

What the [pyqt]Slot decorator actually does is to define a slot signature in the QMetaObject, so that it can be used for various purposes:

- dealing with threading (so that signals may be eventually queued);
- provide proper type matching;
- allow inspection of the QMetaObject, so that all available slots can be listed and interacted with;
- provide external and dynamical usage (through the QMetaObject system), for instance when creating custom widgets as Qt Designer plugins;

99.9% of the times, you won't need any of the above, and slot decorators usually have little benefit performance wise; that's why it's normally completely unnecessary to use them at all.

### Conclusions

Unfortunately, you didn't clarify why you're using pure functions, nor the actual purpose of the decorator.

In reality, you rarely need to connect to pure functions when working with Qt: it is an extremely OOP based toolkit, and, as such, works better when using classes and instances; more precisely, when using QObject subclasses if dealing with signals, slots and properties.

If the purpose of the decorator is to alter the arguments and/or do something with them before or after calling the given function, the `inspect.signature` solution could work, but if you are doing that just to keep track of the given function for other purposes (for instance, calling another function before or after that), you should then just return the original function, just like the Python slot decorator does.

Still, I would strongly suggest you to take your time and consider the implications of what you're doing, the reasons behind it, and the whole object structure.
It's possible that you're just doing it for the wrong reasons or, simply put, in the wrong way.

**Addendum**

I understand your effort in providing an "elegant" solution, but don't ignore the simplicity aspect. Remember the "Zen of Python":

> Simple is better than complex

I don't know if things have changed in the last years, but as far as I know PyQt (and, I suppose, PySide too) emulates the Qt behavior for argument subsets just by doing elementary a try/except loop: when a `TypeError` is raised, it attempts to call the function without the last argument.

The PyQt developer explains it in an [old message](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-October/030595.html) to the PyQt mailing list regarding a very similar issue:

> PyQt emulates the Qt behaviour of allowing a slot to take fewer arguments than the signal is providing.
> It does this by detecting a TypeError raised by the act of calling the slot.

There is no simple way to "do something" when an actual function is called without wrapping it.

Maybe you could do that by subclassing `type` and, among other things, provide a proper implementation in `__call__()`. But this still means that you will still get a "wrapper", not the original function.

I'm not sure it can actually be done, but, not only that would probably be not sufficient: it would also be probably extremely, and in my opinion unnecessarily, complex, not to mention inefficient.

Instead of trying to achieve something as complex as that, consider your purposes: you're not really interested in preserving the original function, but in ensuring that the function properly works even if the signature count of the signal is bigger than what the function actually can accept.

So, you could just do something like this:

```py
def my_decorator(inner):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while args:
            try:
                return inner(*args, **kwargs)
            except TypeError:
                args = args[:-1]

        # last attempt, no positional arguments
        return inner(**kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Obviously, this means that you are not able to track exceptions raised by the function itself (except for the final case), but that can be worked around if you really need it.

Comment: To answer your questions from the second half: my code example is of course highly simplified. My real code is OOP-based, so the slot is a `QMainWindow` member. My decorator simply logs that the name of the method that is called. As such, I do not intend to modify the signature at all - it's just that I have not found a way to log *and* to return `inner` unmodified.

Comment: I could in principle connect the logger and `fun` indepedently to the same signal, but that is error-prone, and `fun` is called from other places (no signals) as well.

Comment: So I think my main question now is, *how* can I "just return the original function, just like the Python slot decorator does". It seems there is something I don't know yet about decorators :)

Comment: I  tried `wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.signature(inner)`, which makes the `inspect.getfullargspec` return the same thing for `wrapper` as well as `inner`, but PySide6 still sees a difference between the two callables. Also, I have not found any pre-/post-call decorator that does not also do something like `inner(*args, **kwargs)`...

Comment: @bers See the addendum in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a pretty perfect answer. I have been able to confirm that `PyQt6` does exactly what you describe: `qpycore_pyqtslot.cpp` has a check for `PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches(xtype, PyExc_TypeError)` and then successively removes arguments `nsa = PyTuple_GetSlice(sa, 0, PyTuple_Size(sa) - 1)`. I am still looking for the same piece of code in `PySide6`, but I am convinced it must be doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to the second part of my question (can I do it): yes, I can:

```py
import inspect
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSpinBox

def fun():
    print("This works, but why?")

def my_decorator(inner):
    signature = inspect.signature(inner)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            return inner()
        return inner(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def decorated_fun():
    print("This fails")

app = QApplication()
box = QSpinBox()
box.valueChanged.connect(fun)
box.valueChanged.connect(decorated_fun)
box.setValue(10)
```

However, I don't think I will ever do something like this. The question remains: is this what PySide6 does, and if so, *why*?